# Node getting created but not inserting into db in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-nodes

I have `Drupal 7` site. I am creating node in my module as follows:-

```
    $newNode = new stdClass();
    $newNode->title = "Hello Node";
    $newNode->type = "product";
    node_object_prepare($newNode); // Sets some defaults.
    $newNode->field_prod_type = 1;
    $newNode->field_prod_cost = 125.00;

    node_submit($newNode); // Prepare node for saving
    node_save($newNode);
```

If I echo the above newNode I do get the successfull created new node id

```
echo "<pre>; print_r($newNode); exit();
```

Issue:- 
**But when I check in the database, I don't see any new record with the above node details.**

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Ao what do you see when you go to yoursite/node/[nidofnewnode] ?
node creation looks fine, but setting values for the fields looks wrong, try without them: 
`$newNode->field_prod_type = 1;`
    `$newNode->field_prod_cost = 125.00;`

Comment: @justtry. Yes you are correct. Node is accessible ' yoursite/node/[nidofnewnode]', but in the database I don't see the values

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [node_object_prepare](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7.x) function to prepare the node values, as you have done.

But the node will not be published (status = 1) and have no user attached (uid = 0?).
And finally, the format of field are always arrays, with 2 dimensions (language and delta).
Then your code must be

```
$newNode->field_prod_type['und'][0] = 1;
$newNode->field_prod_cost['und'][0] = 125.00;
```

Then if you look into your 'node' table, you must have the record for the returned nid. But you cannot have the records in the fields tables ('field_data_field_prod_type' and 'field_data_field_prod_cost') if you don't format it correctly in array...

Do you have any error message when you save your node ?